# How to split string with specific start and end delimiter?

Tags: java, string, collections, split

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "My CID is #encode2#123456789#encode2# I am from India";

    String[] tokens = str.split("#encode2#");

    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        // prints the tokens
        System.out.println(tokens[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Output will be
My CID is
123456789
I am from India

But I want only 123456789 from this whole String and I want to use that 123456789 number for encryption.

I also use if(!"#encode2#".equals(text)) condition but still not getting output.

How to write condition like need strat from #encode2# right part and end before #encode2#.

Comment: Why don't you just ignore the last element in `tokens` array?

Comment: `System.out.println(tokens[0]);` ?

Comment: String is not fix. for example sometime user type big string for example. I am Java and I like to code #encode2#147589545#encode2#. Also I love to learn new programing.


In this case tokens[0] will not work

Answer (score 1):

Use String's [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) and [`lastIndexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(int)) methods to find the index where the two `#encode2#` substrings start. Then, use `substring` to get the string between those two indices.

```
String str = "My CID is #encode2#123456789#encode2# I am from India";
String substring = "#encode2#";
int firstIdx = str.indexOf(substring);
int secondIdx = str.lastIndexOf(substring);
System.out.println(str.substring(firstIdx + substring.length(), secondIdx)); //123456789
```

Comment: You could also use `int firstIdx = str.indexOf(substring) + substring.length(), secondIdx = str.indexOf(substring, firstIdx); … str.substring(firstIdx, secondIdx)` Searching for the next occurrence instead of the last one has different semantics when there are more than two occurrences and for two occurrences, there’s a slight performance difference, depending on which part is expected to be the larger one. It’s up to the OP to decide which is more appropriate.

Comment: @Holger Thanks. I wrote this assuming there are exactly two occurrences of `#encode2#`

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String getToken() {

        String str = "My CID is #encode2#123456789#encode2# I am from India";

        int start = str.indexOf("#encode2#") + "#encode2#".length();
        int end = str.lastIndexOf("#encode2#");

        return str.substring(start, end);
    }
```

Note: This method only works if you have "#encode2#" twice in your String value. If you there are multiple instances of the Token you need, this doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you so much you solve my problem. really helpful

Comment: @Goku No worries. if the answer solved your problem, mark it as correct for others are looking for a solution.